# Dimension scaling of a model hamiltonian system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion

I have a model 2dof double well potential Hamiltonian given as  $$H = P1*P1/2 + P2*P2/2 + V(Q1,Q2) ,$$ where $$V(Q1,Q2) = -2*Q1^2 + Q1^4 - Q2^2 +Q2^4 +0.4*Q1*Q1*Q2*Q2 ,$$ there is no units are provides by the paper, how could i re scale the energy to calculating the quantum states of the system. also compare it with the real Hamiltonian of double well.

Comment: Maybe you can take a few moments to properly typeset question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) so it is displayed in a more standard way.